# Add border-image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

How to add border-image using jquery ?

I'm using the following code:

> jQuery('#footer-area').css('border-image',
>   'url(/sites/all/resources/test.gif) 30 30 round');

And, its not working..

**UPDATE**

**Rendered HTML**

```
<div id="footer-area" class="clearfix" style="border-image-source: url(http://217.64.229.148/sites/all/resources/test.gif); border-image-slice: 30; border-image-width: initial; border-image-outset: initial; border-image-repeat: round; ">
```

Anything missed?

Comment: its is working fine in jsfiddle

Comment: path of the image will be problem check the path,you have to load jquery library,call function in document ready

Comment: Not all browsers support it, maybe that is your issue

Comment: When are you calling this code.

Comment: OP, please provide your rendered HTML as well if you care to get answer for your question...

Comment: How do you call this code? Are you waiting for element to be in DOM? Check, your code works in jsfiddle, so obviously, you are doing something wrong we cannot be aware regarding posted code. Debug it on your side

Comment: Are you running that on document ready event? Is your image url correct? Does your image has enough contrast with background? Does your browser supports `border-image` http://caniuse.com/border-image ?

Comment: Is it not working in *all* browsers? Check the browser support list http://caniuse.com/border-image. I'm thinking that you need to add a class to the footer area instead of applying a style, like `$('#footer-area').addClass('border-image')`. With a class you can provide better browser support.

Comment: @@Wolf.. You are right... Its working in Mozilla and not in IE& Chrome.. Any other fixes for this?

Comment: IE11+ supports border-image, anything under that won't work.

Comment: Also, border-image requires that the element actually has a border before applying this style.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running into browser compatibility issues using this style. For example, Internet Explorer 10 and under does not support this CSS style. Please see this [handy website for browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/border-image).

I personally think you're better off adding a class instead of adding a style in jQuery. By do so, you are providing better browser support. For example, old Firefox requires `-moz-border-image` but more recent versions (Firefox 15+) requires `border-image`. You could do something like:

```
$('#footer-area').addClass('border-image');

.border-image { 
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-image:url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Old firefox */
    -webkit-border-image:url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Safari */
    -o-border-image:url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat; /* Opera */
    border-image:url("/files/4127/border.png") 30 30 repeat;
}
```

Another rule to keep in mind is that `border-image` actually requires a border for this style to be applied to. Notice in my class (above) I have `border: 30px solid transparent;`.